# Python : getcwd and pwd if directory is a symbolic link give different results

Tags: python, directory, path, absolute

If my working directory is a symbolic link, `os.getcwd()` and `os.system("pwd")` do not give the same result. I would like to use `os.path.abspath(".")` to get the full path of my working directory (or a file in it), on purpose, not to get the same result than `os.path.realpath(".")`.

How to get, in python 2.7, something like `os.path.abspath(".", followlink=False)` ?

Example : /tmp is a symbolic link to /private/tmp

```
cd /tmp
touch toto.txt
python
print os.path.abspath("toto.txt")
--> "/private/tmp/toto.txt"
os.system("pwd")
--> "/tmp"
os.getcwd()
--> "/private/tmp"
```

How can I get "/tmp/toto.txt" from the relative path "toto.txt" ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use os.system(), use **os.system("/bin/pwd -L")** to get the logical path for the current working directory.

If running from a bash shell just use "$PWD", or from python use **os.environ["PWD"]** without having to fork a process with **os.system()**.

But **both of these solutions assume you're in the directory where the file is**.

Building on the interface from Eric H:

```
import os,subprocess
def abspath(pathname):
    '''Return logical path (not physical) for pathname using Popen'''
    if pathname[0]=="/":
        return pathname
    lpwd = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/pwd","-L"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].strip()
    return(os.path.join(lpwd,pathname))

def abspathenv(pathname):
    '''Return logical path (not physical) for pathname using bash $PWD'''
    if pathname[0]=="/":
        return pathname
    return(os.path.join(os.environ["PWD"],pathname))

print(abspath("foo.txt"))
print(abspathenv("foo.txt"))
```

Comment: pwd uses the env. PWD variable, so -L is the default option, on my shell. Anyway, using -L is a security.

Comment: Yes the shell builtin "pwd" might use $PWD, but the GNU core utility "/bin/pwd" does not, which was the original intention of using subprocess.Popen or os.system(), I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

A solution is :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def abspath(pathname):
    """ Returns absolute path not following symbolic links. """
    if pathname[0]=="/":
        return pathname
    # current working directory
    cwd = Popen("pwd", stdout=PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].strip()
    return os.path.join(cwd, pathname)

print os.path.abspath("toto.txt")  # --> "/private/tmp/toto.txt"
print abspath("toto.txt")          # --> "/tmp/toto.txt"
```

Comment: I think you need to ensure the "pwd" invoked won't follow symlinks by default, using "pwd -L" should do it.