# taking abspath from os module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created symbolic links for bin and config directories to deployment folder as below:

```
/opt/app/bin -> /opt/deployments/v1/bin
/opt/app/config -> /opt/deployments/v1/config
```

I have a Python file as `/opt/app/bin/pullfiles.py`. I have tried with below code to take abspath of pullfiles.py file:

```
import os
working_dir = f'{os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))[0]}
```

It gives me below result:

```
/opt/deployments/v1
```

but I need actual result:

```
/opt/app
```

Comment: The point of `os.path.realpath` is to eliminate symbolic links. If you want the path of the link instead of the path to the original, don't use `realpath`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would one use both, os.path.abspath and os.path.realpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863476/why-would-one-use-both-os-path-abspath-and-os-path-realpath)

Comment: @khelwood, thanks for response , i have tried with 
working_dir = f'{os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))[0]}

still same result

Comment: @khelwood, os.path.abspath is working only for files , its not working for files under linked directory . i have created symbolic link for directory . i m trying to take abspath for files under bin directory .
source : /opt/deployement/bin/pythonfiles
destination: /opt/app/bin -> /opt/deployment/bin

Comment: If `abspath` doesn't work for you, I suggest you figure out exactly what argument you are passing into `abspath` and exactly what you are getting out, and include those in your question.