# Difference between open(filepath) and open(os.path.abspath(filepath))

Tags: python

Is there any difference between these 2 statements below?

`with open(filepath):`

`with open(os.path.abspath(filepath)):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would one use both, os.path.abspath and os.path.realpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863476/why-would-one-use-both-os-path-abspath-and-os-path-realpath)

Comment: Talking about code behaviour there is no difference at all. Os.path.abspath converts a relative.filepath to absolite path, that's all. Hope this helps

Comment: Abspath removes relative symbols like `.` and `..`

Comment: @JammyDodger Not quite, completely replacing the relative path with the absolute. From `~ / .bashrc` it will make `/home/usr/.bashrc` as from `.bashrc` (if we are at HOME) it will make `/home/usr/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If we ask the difference between the first and second line, it is important to say what the value of `filepath` is.

The behavior is described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) and can be easily tested.

```py
# env: HOME=/home/usr, PWD=/home/usr
from os.path import abspath


filepath1 = ".bashrc"
print(filepath1, abspath(filepath1), sep=" -> ")
# Output: .bashrc -> /home/usr/.bashrc

filepath2 = "~/.bashrc"
print(filepath2, abspath(filepath2), sep=" -> ")
# Output: ~/.bashrc -> /home/usr/.bashrc

filepath3 = "../usr/.bashrc"
print(filepath3, abspath(filepath3), sep=" -> ")
# Output: ../usr/.bashrc -> /home/usr/.bashrc

filepath4 = "/home/usr/.bashrc"
print(filepath4, abspath(filepath4), sep=" -> ")
# Output: /home/usr/.bashrc -> /home/usr/.bashrc

filepath5 = "/tmp/tempfile.txt"
print(filepath5, abspath(filepath5), sep=" -> ")
# Output: /tmp/tempfile.txt -> /tmp/tempfile.txt
```

There is a different behavior in symlinks, the absolute path means the path from the root of the filesystem, not the path to the target. That's why we have `os.path.realpath`, which always returns the "physical" path to the target.

```sh
echo "Hello world!" > /tmp/file_a
ln -s /tmp/file_a /tmp/file_b
```

```py
from os.path import abspath, realpath

path = "/tmp/file_b"

with open(path) as f:
    print(f"File {path} contains: {f.read()}")
    pass

with open(abspath(path)) as f:
    print(f"File {abspath(path)} contains: {f.read()}")
    pass

with open(realpath(path)) as f:
    print(f"File {realpath(path)} contains: {f.read()}")
    pass
```

Output:

```
File /tmp/file_b contains: Hello world!
File /tmp/file_b contains: Hello world!
File /tmp/file_a contains: Hello world!
```